# How can I implement this feature into my pygame program?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am working on a tile/grid treasure hunt game using Pygame and I'm struggling to think of a way to implement this feature. So whenever the user presses space, it checks a specific tile (such as one with a ship) and using a random number (for probability) it should either remove all your coins or do nothing. And whenever you have used space on a tile, you should not be able to reuse that tile again. So these are my issues at the moment.

```
import pygame, sys
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.display.set_caption('My first game')

#colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
brown = (153, 76, 0)
blue  = (0, 0, 255)
grey  = (192,192,192)

#game dimensions
tilesize = 20
mapwidth = 30
mapheight = 20


coins = 0
ship = 1
water = 2
rock = 3
movesMade = 4

#dictionary for texture of the map
textures = { #the transform function scales the photo to the tile size
    ship : pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('ship.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    water: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('water.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    rock: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('rock.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    coins: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('chest.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    movesMade: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))
    }

inventory = {
    coins: 0,
    ship: 0,
    rock: 0,
    movesMade: 0
    }

#image that will represent player
PLAYER = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))

#position of the player
playerPos = [0,0]

resources = [coins, movesMade]

#utilise list comprehension to create grid
tilemap = [[water for w in range(mapwidth)] for h in range(mapheight)]

pygame.init()

#set up display
displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth*tilesize,mapheight*tilesize + 60))

invfont = pygame.font.Font('FreeSansBold.ttf', 18)

#loops through each row
for rw in range(mapheight):
    for cl in range(mapwidth):
        randomnumber = random.randint(0,15)
        if randomnumber == 0 or randomnumber == 1:
            tile = rock
        elif randomnumber == 2 or randomnumber == 3 :
            tile = ship
        else:
            tile = water
        #sets position in the grid
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

while True:
    #user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < mapwidth - 1:
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < mapheight -1:
                playerPos[1] += 1
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                if currentTile == rock:
                    p = 10
                    while p > 0:
                        ran1 = random.randint(0,p)
                        if ran1 % 2 == 0:
                            inventory[coins] == inventory[coins] - inventory[coins]
                            p = p - 1
                        else:
                            p = p - 1

                elif currentTile == ship:
                    inventory[coins] += 50
                    inventory[movesMade] += 1

    #loops through each row 
    for row in range(mapheight):
        #loops through each column in row
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            displaysurf.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilesize,row*tilesize))

    displaysurf.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*tilesize,playerPos[1]*tilesize))

    placePosition = 10
    for item in resources:
        displaysurf.blit(textures[item],(placePosition, mapheight*tilesize + 20))
        placePosition += 30
        #text displays amount of coin
        textObj = invfont.render(str(inventory[item]), True, white, black)
        displaysurf.blit(textObj,(placePosition, mapheight*tilesize + 20))
        placePosition += 50

    #if inventory[coins] > 100:
    #    break
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: The problem is when I do run the code, and I press space on a rock tile, nothing happens. In addition I can use that tile again which should not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So whenever the user presses space, it checks a specific tile (such as one with a ship) and using a random number (for probability) it should either remove all your coins or do nothing [...]

`==` is the compare operator. So `inventory[coins] == inventory[coins] - inventory[coins]` compares `inventory[coins]`  to `0` (`inventory[coins] - inventory[coins]`) and the result goes no where.

If you have fixed the issue, then the `while` loop would do 10 checks. The probability that the coins will be lost is very high:

> ```
> p = 10
> while p > 0:
>     ran1 = random.randint(0,p)
>     if ran1 % 2 == 0:
>         inventory[coins] = inventory[coins] - inventory[coins]
>         p = p - 1
>     else:
>         p = p - 1
> ```

Define a percentage (`percent`) value which defines that the coins are not lost and check if the random value exceeds the limit:

```py
percent = 30 # coins are kept with a probability of 30 percent and will be lost by 70 percent 
ran1 = random.randint(0,100) # random value in [0, 99]
    if ran1 >= percent:
    inventory[coins] = 0
```

---

> [...] And whenever you have used space on a tile, you should not be able to reuse that tile again.

Create a dictionary which stores the information about the "uses"  tiles:

```py
visit = {}
```

Mark a tile "used" if space was pressed:

```py
pos = (playerPos[1], playerPos[0])
visit[pos] = True
```

Check if a tile is already "used" right before:

```py
pos = (playerPos[1], playerPos[0])
if not pos in visit:
    # [...]
```

---

By the way use [`pygame.Surface.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) to clear the display at the begin of every frame.

```py
displaysurf.fill(black) # choose background color
```

---

Main loop code listig:

```py
visit = {}
while True:

    displaysurf.fill(black) # choose background color

    #user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < mapwidth - 1:
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < mapheight -1:
                playerPos[1] += 1
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                pos = (playerPos[1], playerPos[0])
                if not pos in visit:
                    visit[pos] = True
                    currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                    if currentTile == rock:
                        percent = 30 # coins are kept with a probability of 30 percent and will be lost by 70 percent 
                        ran1 = random.randint(0,100) # random value in [0, 99]
                        if ran1 >= percent:
                            inventory[coins] = 0

                    elif currentTile == ship:
                        inventory[coins] += 50
                        inventory[movesMade] += 1
    # [...]
```